# Camera not detecting red colour in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing a program to identify red and green colours from the output of a camera, and my camera can't detect red colours. I've tried changing the red values but it still doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know where I went wrong? Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
red_lower = np.array([156,43,46])
red_upper = np.array([180,255,255])#这里是设置颜色
green_lower=np.array([35,43,46])
green_lower=np.array([77,255,255])
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3, 320)
cap.set(4, 240)

while 1:
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
   # 图像学膨胀腐蚀
   mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
   mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
   res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
   # 寻找轮廓并绘制轮廓
   cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

   if len(cnts) > 0:
       # 寻找面积最大的轮廓并画出其最小外接圆
       cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
       (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
       cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (255, 0, 255), 2)
       # 找到物体的位置坐标,获得颜色物体的位置，可以来控制小车的转向
       print(int(x), int(y))
   else:
       pass
   cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
   cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
   cv2.imshow('res', res)
   if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
       break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error codes are as follows:
Redeclared 'mask' defined above without usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code says

```py
red_lower = np.array([156,43,46])
red_upper = np.array([180,255,255])
```

that means you only consider hue "angles" of 312 to 360 degrees, which is red with a touch of magenta.

red is defined to be around angle 0.

what about angles on the positive side of 0 degrees, red with a touch of yellow?

you'll need to widen your range of hues. you'll need to define another two bounds to catch hues on the positive side of 0 degrees, then use a "bitwise or" operation to combine both ranges of red into one mask.

[image: teaching aid]

(if you found this answer useful, please accept and vote on it. thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

"Redeclared 'mask' defined above without usage" is not an error, but it's a hint your IDE is giving as to what's going wrong here.

The second line in

```
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
```

practically does nothing since you immediately reassign `mask =`  afterwards.

If you want to combine two masks, you could use `bitwise_or`:

```
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
   green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
   mask = cv2.bitwise_or(red_mask, green_mask)
```